# Calculation of percentage value

Tags: sql, percentage

I want to calculate percentage of a value bigger than a threshold by sql like in excel(COUNTIF/COUNT)

Thanks for help

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `avg()` and `case`:

```
select avg(case when a > 2 then 1.0 else 0 end)
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution **without AVG()**, using subqueries.

Run it here: 
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pm4VyShqzNBMpceCzgzniZ/7

```
SELECT NumberOfValid, 
       NumberOfAll, 
       NumberOfValid/NumberOfAll AS "Ratio of Valid/All" 
FROM   (SELECT Count(*) AS NumberOfValid 
        FROM   test 
        WHERE  id < 9) AS subquery1, 
       (SELECT Count(*) AS NumberOfAll 
        FROM   test) AS subquery2;
```

Please note that **this solution is more complicated, but more flexible**. AVG() will always divide by the COUNT() of the whole set, yet with subqueries, you have full control. In this case, AVG() is perfect, but *in other cases, subqueries may be necessary.*